# Redirecting all URLs with extension to no extension, including in subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm looking for a way in which I could redirect `https://example.com/foo.php` to `https://example.com/foo` and also `https://example.com/foo/` to `https://example.com/foo`.

There are copious solutions to this posted on Stack Overflow, but none of them transpire to address an instance where the user tries to access a file such as `https://example.com/foo/bar/baz.php`.

Could anyone kindly propose something to solve this with .htaccess?

The code I have currently is:

```
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+).php
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)/\s
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Please post Your code

Comment: I've updated the post  with my existing code, @starkeen - thanks :)

Comment: You code looks like it should work. what exactly is  your problem?

Comment: When navigating to a file such as `https://example.com/foo/bar/` I get 'XXXX redirected you too many times.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On 

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Remember to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: I was about to post an exact same answer , Actually The Cond2/rule2 was culprit :)

Comment: Yes that's right if `/foo/` is a directory then `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` will safeguard that.